# C++ Multiplication Table

Tags: c++

I need to create a multiplication table but with very specific directions. I have everything working, except one part. An example of the output has to look like this:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
2  4  6  8 10 12 14
3  6  9 12 15 18 21
4  8 12 16 20 24 28
```

My output looks like this, but the code I wrote to do this has a space character at the end of each row (i.e. a space character after 7, 14, 21, 28), and I can't have that. Here's my output:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
2  4  6  8 10 12 14 
3  6  9 12 15 18 21 
4  8 12 16 20 24 28
```

If you highlight each table, you can see the top one doesn't include the space character at the end of each row, but the bottom one does.

I asked my professor and he said I'd have to write a special case for this, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0;

  cin >> x;
  cin >> y;

  for(b = 1; b <= y; ++b){
    for(a = 1; a <= x; ++a){
      cout << setw(2) << a * b << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What can I do to achieve this? I know it's a confusing question so let me know if yall need any further explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered only printing the space character when `a < x`?

Comment: Well, you write a space, so that space appears in your output. Just don't write it to fix your code. However, perhaps easier, check out `setw()` at cppreference.com.

Comment: If at the first column, don't print a space, otherwise print a space before printing the number.  Or use `setw` and right justification (the `cout` will fill in spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int a = 0;
//  int y = 0; this  is the error btw you can't re declare variable
  int b = 0; //this is what you wanted i guess

  cin >> x;
  cin >> y;

  for(b = 1; b <= y; ++b){
    for(a = 1; a < x; ++a){
      cout << setw(2) << a * b << " ";
    }
    cout <<setw(2)<< b * x << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple `if` statement to write output without space at loop's last iteration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int a = 0;
  int y = 0;

  cin >> x;
  cin >> y;

  for(b = 1; b <= y; ++b){
    for(a = 1; a <= x; ++a){
      if (a == x) cout << setw(2) << a * b;
      else cout << setw(2) << a * b << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional operator to improve readability.

```
cout << setw(2) << a * b << (a==x ? "" : " ");
```